# List for both checkedlist box and combobox

Tags: c#, list, combobox, checkedlistbox

I want to add all selected items of checkedlistbox and combobox to a list and use that list in a for each loop in c#

I tried this

```
List<String> list=new List<String>();

if (rbtnMultipleScenario.Checked == true)
{
    foreach ( CheckedListBox str in clbScenario.SelectedItems)
    {                    
         lstitems.Add(str);
    }                  
}
```

By using String, I am not able to add all the selected items of Checkedlistbox.

Which type of list I have to use?

Comment: Because there is no overload of `List<T>.Add` method that takes `CheckedListBox` as a parameter. Why don't you try with `.Text` or `.ValueMember` (which one is exist) property instead?

Comment: Actually, you can use List<CheckedListBox> without a problem thanks to the "T" parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> list=new List<string>();

if (rbtnMultipleScenario.Checked == true)
{
    foreach ( string str in clbScenario.SelectedItems)
    {                    
         lstitems.Add(str);
    }                  
}
```

This assumes that SelectedItems contains a collection of strings (which by your exception it does)

Comment: Exception-----unable to cast object of type System.String to type System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox

Comment: What objects are you using to build up your select list box collection (in clbScenario)?

    clbScenario.SelectedItems

is a collection of objects - if you've added strings into it then you'll get strings out. I'll update my answer

Comment: How can i add all the selected items of checkedlistbox in the foreach loop?

Comment: For String it was not taking all selected items in  .SelectedItems

Comment: Can you show your code that is adding the items to the clbScenario for display in the UI? I wonder if you're mixing types.